# Uncheck a check box when a specific check box is unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes on my form `extraOption2` and `extraOption3` I successfully managed to make `extraOption2` **auto checked** when the user check `extraOption3` but I am not still able to make `extraOption3` got unchecked when the user unchecks `extraOption3`

The HTML code that I am using:

```js
var checkboxesToCheck1 = [
  // TODO: Add here the HTML IDs of checkboxes to check -->
  'extraOption2',
  'extraOption3',
];

var vifield = document.getElementById('extraOption3');

vifield.onclick = function() {
  checkboxesToCheck1.forEach(
    function(id, index) {
      document.getElementById(id).checked = vifield.checked;
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <input type="hidden" name="extraOption2Title" value="Extra Option 2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="extraOption2" class="inp-cbx" name="extraOption2" value="5.00" />
    <label class="cbx" for="extraOption2">
<span>
<svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
<polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
</svg>
</span>
<span id="extraOption2Title">Invoicing $5/m</span>
</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <input type="hidden" name="extraOption3Title" value="Extra Option 3" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="extraOption3" class="inp-cbx" name="extraOption3" value="5.00" />
    <label class="cbx" for="extraOption3">
<span>
<svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
<polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
</svg>
</span>
<span title="Requires: Invoicing" id="extraOption3Title">Sales $5/m </span>
</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can use that code to make `extraOption3` auto-checked / unchecked when `extraOption2` is checked / unchecked but I want some code to allow the user to auto-check `extraOption3` when `extraOption2` is unchecked to allow the user to choose `extraOption2` without the need to get `extraOption3` but not the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you well:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
  <input type="hidden" name="extraOption2Title" value="Extra Option 2" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="extraOption2" class="inp-cbx" name="extraOption2" value="5.00" />
  <label class="cbx" for="extraOption2">
    <span>
      <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
        <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span id="extraOption2Title">Invoicing $5/m</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
  <input type="hidden" name="extraOption3Title" value="Extra Option 3" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="extraOption3" class="inp-cbx" name="extraOption3" value="5.00" />
  <label class="cbx" for="extraOption3">
    <span>
      <svg width="12px" height="10px" viewbox="0 0 12 10">
        <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span title="Requires: Invoicing" id="extraOption3Title">Sales $5/m </span>
  </label>
</div>


<script>
var checkboxesToCheck1 = [
  'extraOption2',
  'extraOption3',
];

var vifield = document.getElementById('extraOption3');
var vifield2 = document.getElementById('extraOption2');

vifield.onclick = function () {
  if (document.getElementById('extraOption2').checked &&            !document.getElementById('extraOption3').checked) {
    document.getElementById('extraOption3').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('extraOption2').checked = true;
  } else { 
  checkboxesToCheck1.forEach(
    function (id, index) {
      document.getElementById(id).checked = vifield.checked;
    }
  );
  }
}
vifield2.onclick = function () {
  if (!document.getElementById('extraOption2').checked && document.getElementById('extraOption3').checked) {
  checkboxesToCheck1.forEach(
    function (id, index) {
      document.getElementById(id).checked = false;
    }
  );
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. The code is working however when "extraOption2" and "extraOption3" are both checked the user cannot uncheck "extraOption2", I need the user to be able to uncheck"extraOption2" when "extraOption3" is check and when he do that both checkboxes will be unchecked

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. The code is working however when "extraOption2" and "extraOption3" are both checked the user cannot uncheck "extraOption2", I need the user to be able to uncheck"extraOption2" when "extraOption3" is check and when he do that both checkboxes will be unchecked

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is linked checkboxes exactly like the one on this page: https://www.odoo.com/pricing    some of the checkboxes requires other checkboxes to be checked so it auto check them and when required checkboxes got unchecked they uncheck the boxes they require

Comment: Now you have sorted it by 90%, thanks
The only issue now is when the user unchecks "extraOption3" it force "extraOption2" to be unchecked. 
I need when "extraOption3" is checked "extraOption2" will be checked to but when the user unchecks "extraOption3" I need "extraOption2" not to be affected like odoo.com/pricing

Comment: The code is very ugly now(need to be rewritten) , but it works i think, check it pls

Comment: When I checked both options and tried to uncheck "extraOption2" it didn't uncheck "extraOption3"
On checking "extraOption2" I need "extraOption3" to be unchecked too. but when I unchecked "extraOption3" i need "extraOption2" to remain checked

Comment: you kidding me .) it works exactly as you described :) check it